# After "Checking battery state" error lowered resolution

Tags: resolution

I had suddenly the above, well known error message, after rebooting and installing nvidia drivers (nvidia-current) the loading screen is full sized, but the login screen is 640x480. And after logging in also the same screen size. How to raise screen size settings, I even dont have menu only comman line in this small resolution.

I tried xrandr but no success. Any idea?
v12.10

Comment: @Web-E post it as an answer if you've got time (and so you get credit for the solution), so that the question can be marked as answered :)

Comment: If its *solved* please mark the answer as good by pressing the small check mark next to it, dont edit the tile to reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `xorg.conf` file and try rebooting.

Use the below command to rename the original file. So that if this change cause any problem, you can revert back.

`sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak`